# how to prevent matlab from cutting decimals?

Tags: matlab

I try to store this value

alphaSqrt = 0.006694380022903415749574948586;

However matlab always cut it. Is there a way to store the whole value?

Comment: MATLAB isn't capping anything.  It's the way the number is being displayed.  By default, MATLAB displays numbers up to 4 decimal places.  You need to change the way MATLAB displays numbers  When you type in that number, the precision is maintained so don't mistake the way MATLAB displays numbers with anything dealing with accuracy.  See the duplicate answer for more details.

Comment: thx but in my case format long is not enough, and after 16 I think it's troncated. Is there a way to check? Because I need a value with 35 digits

Comment: You need to perhaps use the `vpa` module for that.  http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/vpa.html.  BTW, do you seriously need 35 digits?  It gets to a point where adding more precision to a number doesn't help with the application.

Comment: I wouldn't need it... but it's something ask by a teacher :|

Comment: :S... ok.. definitely look at the `vpa` module.  However, this number is defined **symbolically**.  Converting back to a finite type (`double` for example) will still truncate the number of decimal points.

Comment: thanks a lot!! Will read it. Much appreciated

Comment: @rayryeng So actually, it's not a duplicate. Maybe remove the link (which is by the way marked as a duplicate itself)?

Comment: If you want to do *efficient* calculations with numbers like these, you need a quadruple-precision floating-point format. Matlab only supports single-precision and double-precision by default. You could look into these toolboxes: http://www.advanpix.com/, http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/6446-multiple-precision-toolbox-for-matlab

Comment: thanks!! It also proved really useful. If you post it as answer I could mark it, because the answer already suggested doesn't solve case for huge numbers.

Comment: I will remove the duplicate when the question has changed or added new constant to reflect what is really being sought. Currently, the question can be interpreted in a way we're solving the problem is to fool around with `format`. If the information in the comments are added, I'll reopen the question.